# Python Selenium: find_element_by_link_text doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium

I've been using Python's Selenium bindings with PyCharm CE for three years now and never had any problems with its functions.

But now I'm encountering a very weird error when trying to use find_element_by_link_text as in

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Administration").click()
```

The error reads as followed:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: this.each is not a function
```

Other find_element_by functions work perfectly fine.

After updating all my packages including `selenium` to 4.0 I received this warning in addition to the above:

```
UserWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  warnings.warn("find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead")
```

I downgraded `selenium` to 3.141.0 again, but then I just receive the `this.each`error again without any warnings.

I also tried other different approaches given by selenium.dev such as

```
browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, value="Administration")
```

but they don't seem to work either.

What has changed? What do I have to change? Why do all other similar find_element functions like id/xpath/visible_text/etc. work? I'm at my wits' end, and I don't want to rewrite all my find_element_by_link_text calls. :(

Comment: this has since been fixed: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/eMX3DGtXQ48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function finally works with Chrome 83 Beta and Chromedriver 83, and it looks like the problem was caused by the older Chromedriver version, incorrectly calling prototype.js.

Patch notes for version 83:

"Updated Chromedriver to work correctly with prototype.js."